# Azure Media Services freezes on Android

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, smooth-streaming

im using Azure Media Services along with Azure Media Player to play smooth stream, works fine on desktop but on Android Chrome when i open the video, he appears to be freeze like an image of the first frame from the video.
Anyone have any idea why is that happening?

Android v6.0.0
Google Chrome v56.0.2924.87

Comment: Hey Henrique, can you reproduce the issue by playing back the video on our test page? http://aka.ms/azuremediaplayer

Comment: Works properly on your page, i could fix it by adding a play button, since the autoplay feature doesnt work for Android, but now im having a similar issue with IOS

Comment: if the asset is working on the demo page, there's potentially an issue with the implementation in the application you're testing. Would you mind posting your code? Or sending the details/ a repro link to ampinfo@microsoft.com ?